# XAMPP Apache can't start because PHP can't find VCREDIST140.DLL >=14.29

Tags: windows, xampp, vcredist

XAMPP control panel error log:

```
7:08:18 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
[...]
7:08:18 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs [...] for more clues
```

C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log

```
[...]
PHP Warning:  'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll' 14.15 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.29 in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Jun 13 19:07:15.035078 2022] [:emerg] [pid 5580:tid 416] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** XAMPP's PHP wants vcruntime140.dll to be version 14.29 or above. It looks for this file at C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140.dll, finds version 14.15, and fails to start.

**Solution:** Version 14.32 is present in the same folder, but PHP does not find it, so we copy that file (vcruntime140d.dll) to C:\xampp\apache\bin, and rename it to vcruntime140.dll (remove the d) which solves the problem.

**Note:** This might not be the *right* solution, ie. it neither identifies nor addresses the root issue, but it works and I have to get back to work.

Answer (score 1):

you need to update Visual C++ Redistributable Packages in windows

download this file this will solve this issue

https://www.mediafire.com/file/j2bggc1ms8geb9l/6_use_this_folder_if_setup_failed.zip/file